# How to check if $x$ equals a certain value $y$ with while loops, addition and substraction

Tags: algorithms

Consider, we are only allowed to use loops ($while$), addition ($+$), substraction ($-$) and checking if a value is $> 0$. How can one find out, if a certain variable $x$ equals a value $y$?  E.g. how can I find out if $x=4$ by only using the aforementioned methods? For $x=0$ I came up with the following:

```
y = 1
while x > 0:
    y = y - 1
    x = x - 1
while y > 0:
   do something
```

This way, $something$ gets only executed if $x=0$. But I have no clue about values above $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by calculating $x-y$. This is simple enough:

```
while y > 0:
    y -= 1
    x += 1
```

Now, compare what you got with $0$. That is, compare the value of $x$ *after* the loop to $0$, using the technique you thought of. This will guarantee that "$something$" is executed only if $x-y=0$, or equivalently if $x=y$.